# How to write text over an image using scikit-image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image

I know how to do this with OpenCV and PIL. I can't use OpenCV in this project and if I use PIL I have to convert in between image PIL Image and numpy array. I don't want to do that. I'm already using skimage so...

**How do I write text on top of an image using skimage?**

I've looked at the skimage draw functions, but they seem to only handle shapes and lines not text. Maybe I'm searching the wrong words, but I don't see anything in the docs.

Comment: "if I use PIL I have to convert in between image PIL Image and numpy array. I don't want to do that." Why? Usually, a view to the memory location is used and no data is copied: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray

Comment: Oh, apparently, I'm wrong: https://uploadcare.com/blog/fast-import-of-pillow-images-to-numpy-opencv-arrays/  Still, you could use PIL to generate a text image and paste that into the existing one using skimage/numpy. This way, you at least avoid copying the original image.

Answer (score 2):

```py
%matplotlib inline
from skimage.draw import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
rr, cc = rectangle(start=(0, 0), extent=(1, 4))
img = np.zeros((5, 5, 3), dtype=np.int32)
img[rr, cc, 0] = 0
img[rr, cc, 1] = 255
img[rr, cc, 2] = 255
plt.text(2, 2, "some text", dict(color='red', va='center', ha='center'))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
```

You can use matplotlib to draw text, since scikit-image is also using matplotlib as backend

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sarim. You should use opencv here

```
import cv2
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#img is your image in below line
cv2.putText(img,'Text on image goes here',(10,500), font, 1,(255,255,255),2)
#Display the image
cv2.imshow("img",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I can't use opencv, but I can use scikit. That's the whole point.